# Determine if given addresses are 4k or 8k aligned

Tags: memory

I have been given a list of 8 memory addresses.  I need to determine which of the addresses are 4k aligned and which are 8k aligned.  The addresses are:

```
55ee61199008

55ee61199000

55ee6119A000

55ee6119A100

80ee61199008

ee61199000

80ee6119A000

80ee6119A100
```

I am not sure how to tell which are aligned.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Is the question which addresses are at the start of 4k or 8k segments? Or which addresses are within the same 4k or 8k segment?

Comment: I believe it is which addresses are at the start of 4k or 8k segments.  We are studying page tables and discussing where things are stored in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4k memory segments start at a hex address ending with 000. So all the addresses that end with 000 start on a 4 k boundary.

However, addresses that end with 0000, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, a000, c000, or e000 also start on an 8k boundary. This is because hex 1000 is 4k or 2^12. And hex 2000 is 8k or 2^13. Boundaries start at multiples of 4k or 8k.

Thus 55ee61199000 starts on a 4k boundary. While 55ee6119A000 starts on both a 4k and 8k boundary.